# Why press F12 go to type definition rather then definition?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press **F12** or **ctrl click**, it goes to a index.d.ts, but I think it should go to a .js/.ts source file.
It behaves same as **Go to Type Definition**.

Is this a bug? Or is there any setting about this?

Here is my VScode about information and the platform is macOS:

> Version: 1.63.2 (Universal) 
> Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
> Date: 2021-12-15T09:37:28.172Z
> Electron: 13.5.2
> Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
> Node.js: 14.16.0
> V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
> OS: Darwin arm64 21.2.0